# What is the appropiate way to retain a fragment state in Master/Detail?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fragments are added to back stack.If FragmentOne is displayed in portrait and screen is rotated to landscape mode, fragmentTwo would show. Then, if screen is rotated again, fragmentOne is redisplayed( displayed as new fragment?) in portrait mode. What is the most efficient way to solve this problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MasterFragment.OnMasterSelectedListener {

FragmentOne mFragmentOne;
Fragmenttwo mFragmentTwo;

Boolean dualPane;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    mFragmentTwo = new Fragmenttwo();


    MasterFragment masterFragment;
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    FrameLayout frameLayoutDetail = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutDetail);

    if (frameLayout !=null ) {
        dualPane= false;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "single Pane ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        masterFragment=(MasterFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MASTER");
        if (masterFragment==null) {
            masterFragment = new MasterFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, masterFragment,"MASTER");
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }else {
        if (frameLayoutDetail !=null) {
            dualPane = true;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dual Pane ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            masterFragment=(MasterFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayoutMaster);
            if (masterFragment==null) {
                masterFragment = new MasterFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutMaster, masterFragment);
            }
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(int position) {

    if (!dualPane) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you clicked 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFragmentOne)
                        .addToBackStack(null);
                        //.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFragmentTwo)
                        .addToBackStack(null);
                //.commit();
                break;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }else {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you clicked 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutDetail, mFragmentOne)
                        .addToBackStack(null);
                //.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutDetail, mFragmentTwo)
                        .addToBackStack(null);
                //.commit();
                break;
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

}

MasterFragment:

```
public class MasterFragment extends ListFragment {

OnMasterSelectedListener mCallback;

public interface OnMasterSelectedListener {
    void onItemSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    String[] numbers = new String[]{"One", "Two"};
    ListAdapter numAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);
    setListAdapter(numAdapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnMasterSelectedListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnMasterSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    mCallback.onItemSelected(position);
    //getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

}

FragmetOne:

```
public class Fragmenttwo extends Fragment {

public Fragmenttwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
}

}
```

FragmentTwo:

```
public class Fragmenttwo extends Fragment {

public Fragmenttwo() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //setRetainInstance(true);
    // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
    //outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
}
```

}